# Pressure difference between one moving fluid and a stationary fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, bernoulli-equation

I'm trying to understand how exactly we can show that the pressure of a fluid $x$ is lower or greater than the pressure of a fluid $y$.

One good example I found is the following image.

[image]

Using Bernoulli's principle we can show that the pressure of an incompressible and steady fluid will decrease as the velocity increase. However, nothing tell us that the pressure of a moving fluid $x$ is lower or greater than a stationary fluid $y$. How can we explain this phenomena?